How to extract text from PDF on exception "'>' not expected"
Extracting text from PDF using latest iText from nuGet
  MemoryStream pdfStream = ...
  pdfStream.Position = 0;
  var strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
  var reader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
  using var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader);
  for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); ++i)
  {
    var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
    var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
  }

throw exception at GetTextFromPage():
 iText.IO.Exceptions.IOException: Error at file pointer 39747.  --->
 iText.IO.Exceptions.IOException: '>' not expected.    --- End of inner
 exception stack trace ---    at
 iText.IO.Source.PdfTokenizer.ThrowError(String error, Object[]
 messageParams)    at iText.IO.Source.PdfTokenizer.NextToken()    at
 iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Util.PdfCanvasParser.NextValidToken()  
 at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Util.PdfCanvasParser.ReadObject()   
 at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Util.PdfCanvasParser.Parse(IList`1
 ls)    at
 iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[]
 contentBytes, PdfResources resources)    at
 iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.ProcessPageContent(PdfPage
 page)    at
 iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfPage
 page, ITextExtractionStrategy strategy, IDictionary`2
 additionalContentOperators)    at
 iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfPage
 page, ITextExtractionStrategy strategy)

PDF is at
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/340cd26ec3b600354b36f368ac4bf9af20240517055159/56d39d
How to extract text from this PDF ?
